# Dynamically triggering a jQuery function using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

In PHP it is possible to chain a method dynamically using a variable. For example:

```
$foo = 'myFunction';
return $this->{$foo};
```

I was wondering if a similar possibility exists in jQuery and/or Javascript. So for example:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '[function-attribute=myFunction]', function(){
    var foo = $(this).attr('function-attribute');

    return {foo}();
});
```

I understand the code above does not work but just hopefully gives an impression of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is declared globally then you can access it via the `window` using bracket notation:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '[function-attribute=myFunction]', function(){
  var foo = $(this).attr('function-attribute');
  return window[foo]();
});
```

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was looking for thank you! I'll accept the answer as soon as I"m allowed (10 minutes)